# Download Solr Collection config from specific directory on ZK

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

We have Solr collections' config details in a specific directory on Zookeeper. Below is the directory structure on **zookeeper**;

```
|--app_dir
   |--dev
     |--configs
        |--collection_name
            |--conf
```

I am trying to download the configuration of collections using **downconfig** utility. Following is the command I am using;

```
bin/solr zk downconfig -n conf_name -d /home/ec2-user/solr-8.1.0/server/solr/configsets  -z zk-dev-1:2181,zk-dev-2:2181,zk-dev-3:2181
```

The command fails to execute with below error,

```
ERROR: Error downloading files from zookeeper path /configs/test_vector to /home/ec2-user/solr-8.1.0/server/solr/configsets/conf

ERROR - 2020-09-30 15:11:23.778; org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI; Could not complete downconfig operation for reason: Error downloading files from zookeeper path /configs/test_vector to /home/ec2-user/solr-8.1.0/server/solr/configsets/conf
```

I suspect the path for config is incorrect as the actual path is `app_name/dev/configs/collection_name` while the error suggests the path is only `configs/collection_name` but I am not sure if that's the error.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you're not using the default `/solr` path inside ZK, you should be able to change it using `-zkhost 127.0.0.1:2181/app_dir/dev`

Comment: @MatsLindh This resolved my issue. Can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using the default `/solr` path inside ZK, you should be able to change it using

```
-zkhost 127.0.0.1:2181/app_dir/dev
```

This is also required for any configuration of a SolrCloud compatible (i.e. Zookeeper-aware) client or other operations that interact with Zookeeper.